# Android SDK on LINUX arm64 docker

Tags: android, docker, android-sdk-tools

I recently switched to a M1 MacBook Pro and I am struggling to understand how to re-build  part of my dev environment: a Linux Docker image to build Android apps using fastlane.

If I run the `amd64` image on Docker via rosetta emulation, it works but it is *extremely* slow (on the order of 6-10 times slower).

I researched a bit if it is possible to create an `arm64` image and found few answers.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421230/android-sdk-on-docker-for-arm64-raspberry-pi-4-for-building-apk) there is some research about it
- [Here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/gounthar/arm64-ubuntu-android-sdk/latest/images/sha256-a0fa7403ecc9b3a2278acb2b8db1a13db751a1c612da1f555b121324e6acab30) there is an old docker image that is supposed to work

But nothing I have tried worked (even if I am able to build the images).

The main problem I have is that the entire Android SDK toolchain is only available for `amd64` and even if Debian had at least one [platform compiled](https://packages.debian.org/sid/android-sdk) for `arm64`, I need to have the last 6-7 platforms installed, so as soon as I add anything with `sdkmanager`, the new platforms tools installed contain binaries compiled for `amd64` that obviously do not work.

Has anyone found a (not too nasty) hack to run the latest Android SDk platforms on `arm64`?

I am also willing to compile the entire toolchain from source, but I am am not sure which version of the tools for each platform should be built and how to configure the single platforms to use them.